# PFQuery Ignoring [queryViews findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)

Tags: parsing, parse-platform

I have been working with Parse for over a year now with limited issues. Until today. I have done a very basic query to return if a row exists or does not. When stepping through the code it simply skips the if condition and continues to return nothing from the query. Skips this line in particular..

```
[queryViews findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
```

Here is the odd part. I have another query a few lines down calling a different table (within Parse) which returns data. The only difference is that I'm calling the query via a button action where as with this one I'm trying to use is via viewDidLoad().

I'm fairly confident the code is correct but I'm truly stuck as I can't figure out why its simple skipping. Below is my code, any ideas?

```
    PFQuery *queryViews = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Views"];
queryViews.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
[queryViews whereKey:@"Active" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[queryViews whereKey:@"ViewName" equalTo:@"MissingTotemButton"];
[queryViews findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            //NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            NSLog(@"desc%@",object.objectId);

            PFObject *viewActive = [object objectForKey:@"Active"];
            if ([viewActive isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]])
            {
                self.missingTotem.alpha = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Jeremy

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. My query never hits the completionBlock. I'm stumped. Any clues?

Comment: It starting working I have no explanation to why it stopped. I ended up reviewing the code and cleaning the project and it started working. It could have been an issue with Parse on that day. Since then no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working again. Clearly a user error. I'm really not sure what I did to make it work. I cleaned the project a few times then build it, then executed it. Perhaps it had an issue with the network. Anyway the code above does work. Just unsure what made it work.

Hope that helps someone.

Jeremy